# Trying to create a multi select gridview for gallery in Android, but the picture is not displaying in gridview

Tags: java, android, image, gridview, multi-select

I am able to see the gridview with checkbox and a blank boxes. I don't understand why the pictures are not getting set to the boxes.

My imageAdapter getView() method code below:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "getView Position " + position + " devicePhoto " + images.get(position).photoID);

   ViewHolder holder;


    if (convertView == null) {
      holder            = new ViewHolder();

        //View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.articles_list_row, parent, false);
        convertView       = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo, parent, false);
        holder.imageview  = (SnapFullSizeImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        holder.checkbox   = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_checkbox);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.checkbox.setId(position);
    holder.imageview.setId(position);

    holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            int id = cb.getId();

            if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
              thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
            } else {
              cb.setChecked(true);
              thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
            }
        }
    });

   if (holder.imageview.getLayoutParams().height != mItemHeight) {

     holder.imageview.setLayoutParams(new     FrameLayout.LayoutParams(GridView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, GridView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }

    if(thumbnailsselection.length >0){
      holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
    }
    holder.id = position;
    holder.imageview.setImageResource(position);

    holder.imageview.setDevicePhoto(images.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

Next my activity page:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
 setHasOptionsMenu(true);

 Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
 String sGallery = bundle.getString("gallery");
 View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_picture_grid, container, false);

   GridView gridView = (GridView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
   this.myImageAdapater = new DeviceImageAdapter(this.getActivity(), bundle.getString("id"), bundle.getString("name"), sGallery, this, gridView, bundle.getInt("parentPosition"));

   mGridView = gridView;
   setToGrid(this, gridView); 
   return inflatedView;
}

public void setToGrid(final PictureGridFragment pictureGridFragment, final GridView gridView) {
    gridView.setAdapter(pictureGridFragment.myImageAdapater);

    Log.i(TAG, "setToGrid");


    gridView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    if (pictureGridFragment.myImageAdapater.getNumColumns() == 0) {
                        final int numColumns = (int) Math.floor(
                                gridView.getWidth() / (getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.image_thumbnail_size) + getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.image_thumbnail_spacing)));
                        if (numColumns > 0) {
                            final int columnWidth =
                                    (gridView.getWidth() / numColumns) - getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.image_thumbnail_spacing);
                            pictureGridFragment.myImageAdapater.setNumColumns(numColumns);
                            pictureGridFragment.myImageAdapater.setItemHeight(columnWidth);
                            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView - numColumns set to " + numColumns);
                            }
                            gridView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                    .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```